# PHP Libsodium Installing Latest Library Failing, Linux Newb

Tags: php, installation, libraries

I installed PHP extension libsodium via PECL on Linux, and everything seemed fine as I started to test the functions, but I've noticed that some functions are working and others are not.

For example, when I call sodium_crypto_generichash and sodium_crypto_secretbox i get no errors, but when i call sodium_crypto_pwhash I get an error in PHP saying sodium_crypto_pwhash is not a function.

I'm new to PHP and Linux but I'm thinking this means my PHP library is out of date. When I call

```
var_dump([
    SODIUM_LIBRARY_MAJOR_VERSION,
    SODIUM_LIBRARY_MINOR_VERSION,
    SODIUM_LIBRARY_VERSION
]);
```

I get

```
array(3){[0]=>int(9)[1]=>int(1)[2]=>string(5)"1.0.8"}
```

And I see at https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/releases the latest release is 1.0.16

So I would like to install the latest library. As I'm new to Linux I'm trying to do this in the terminal and I don't know what to do. these are the steps I followed to this point, starting from my home directory

1. wget https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/releases/download/1.0.16/libsodium-1.0.16.tar.gz (downloads the file ok)
2. tar -xvzf libsodium-1.0.16.tar.gz (unzips the file ok, creates libsodium-1.0.16 directory)
3. cd libsodium-1.0.16 directory
4. Now what?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If that library follows semantic versioning (semver.org), then the jump from 1.0.8 to 1.0.16 will not add new functions but only bugfixes and similar improvements, but no new features. In which version of that library were the functions added?

Comment: it looks like it was added in 1.0.9, a description of the versions can be found at https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/releases

Comment: I managed to install it with ./config, then make, then make install. This installed it to the directory /usr/local/lib. But when I dumb the library var on my webpage it still says library 1.0.8

Comment: and in php info it says sodium support => enabled, sodium compiled version => 2.0.10, libsodium headers version => 1.0.8, libsodium library version => 1.0.8